# Buttons are disappear when i try to get this design

Tags: android

I want to make a calculator with TableLayout. I know it fits better with GridLayout but TableLayout is a must.

I try to get this design:

[image]

As you seae, the numbers(1 to 9) are in the same size and order with connect and disconnect buttons. However, in my current design, Its like that:

but button in my design look like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

TextView titleView = new TextView(this);
titleView.setText("Table Layout");
titleView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(titleView);


LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
layout2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));




Button btnConnect = new Button(this);
btnConnect.setText("Connect");
btnConnect.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
layout2.addView(btnConnect);

TextView titleViewSpace = new TextView(this);
titleViewSpace.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
layout2.addView(titleViewSpace);


Button btnDisconnect = new Button(this);
btnDisconnect.setText("Disconnect");
btnDisconnect.setLayoutParams(new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
layout2.addView(btnDisconnect);

layout.addView(layout2);

TableLayout tblLayout = new TableLayout(this);
tblLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
TableRow tblrow = null;


for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 1) {
        tblrow = new TableRow(this);
        tblLayout.addView(tblrow);

    }
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("" + i);
    tblrow.addView(b);
}




TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
Button btnZero = new Button(this);
btnZero.setText("0");
Button btnHash = new Button(this);
btnHash.setText("#");
Button btnStar = new Button(this);
btnStar.setText("*");


tr.addView(btnZero);
tr.addView(btnHash);
tr.addView(btnStar);


tblLayout.addView(tr);
layout.addView(tblLayout);


setContentView(layout);
```

in order to make my buttons in same order and size with connect and disconnect buttons

i simply do that when i create button in loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 1) {
            tblrow = new TableRow(this);
            tblLayout.addView(tblrow);

        }
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("" + i);
        b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
        tblrow.addView(b);
    }
```

but when i put this LayoutParams:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
```

buttons(1 to 9) are disappered in the screen. Why? How can i overcome with this problem? How can i make button like that in the same screen?

Comment: so why you make your life so hard and you create a view programmatic ally, why not `xml` file?

Comment: because this is must in the assignment.

Comment: my advice for you is to make this view first in xml, then copy and paste correct properties in to the coding style. To make buttons stretch accordingly you should put `LinearLayout's weightSum` property also..

Answer (score 0):

this is all i needed:

```
tblLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
```